# Is there a way to change the volume scatter colour while only having a red light

Tags: lighting, shader-nodes, volumetrics

Volume in blender is a brilliant way to give depth to a scene and can give gorgious god rays, but for the scene im working on i want a different colour fog around the light then the light itself, usually i'd just change the colour value but the problem is the light is pure red and so the volume fog around it can only be red.

is there anything i can do to somehow convert the volume into mapping data that i can plug  into an rgb node or something so i can have control over the volume colour for any scene weather i do or dont have all the lights needed for the variation of colour.

Comment: Hue/saturation node is what pops out to me